# trying to search google in quations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search google for **"music life"** (music life inside quotes)
i am getting error .i tested the url in Firefox it works,also if i change the search to "music" it works(one word) how can i fix this problem

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://google.com/search?q="music life"'
req = urllib.request.Request(
        url,
        data=None,
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        }
    )
html=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.title)
```

output:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: You need to properly encode the params in the url. It will be easier to let requests do this for you. Otherwise, there is probably an `encode` method in the `urllib` somewhere

Comment: @SuperStew even if i don't decode it gives the same error

Comment: Show that code? `q="music life"` isn't properly encoded. Should look like `"music+life"` or something

Comment: @SuperStew it works now thanks,you can post as answer

Answer (score 1):

Change the params in the url to be url encoded like so

```
"music+life"
```

instead of `"music life"`

Or do something like this (note im using requests)

```
import requests
url=r'https://google.com/search'

params={'q':'"music life"'}

r=requests.get(url,params=params)

r.status_code
>200
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by SuperStew, the issue is with the url encoding of your search parameters.

To adapt your existing code, you just need to encode the search term properly:

```py
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search = "music life"
url = "https://google.com/search?q=" + urllib.parse.quote_plus(search)
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url,
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.title)
```